# Bash: Replace values of a column while retaining line order.

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed, string-comparison

I have a file, FILE1, of some 19.000 lines that has the following format:

```
PAAXXXX PAAXXXX 0 0 1 -9
PAAXXXY PAAXXXY 0 0 1 -9
PAAXXYX PAAXXYX 0 0 2 -9
PAAXYXX PAAXYXX 0 0 2 -9
PAAYXXX PAAYXXX 0 0 1 -9
PAAYYXX PAAYYXX 0 0 1 -9
PAAYYYX PAAYYYX 0 0 2 -9
PAAAAAB PAAAAAB 0 0 1 -9
```

The IDs in columns 1 and 2 are the same in each case, col 3 and 4 are always 0, col 5 is either 1 or 2 and col 6 is always -9.

I have two more files, FILE2 and FILE3, which contain only IDs and do not overlap. For example:

```
head -3 FILE2
    PAAXXYX 
    PAAXYXX
    PAAYXXX

head -2 FILE3
    PAAYYYX
    PAAAAAB
```

I would like to change the value of col6 in FILE1 based on overlapping of col1 or col2 with the IDs in files 2 and 3. Specifically, I would like to assign 1 to column 6 for all IDs found in FILE2 and 2 for all IDs found in FILE3. My final output might therefore look something like this:

```
PAAXXXX PAAXXXX 0 0 1 -9
PAAXXXY PAAXXXY 0 0 1 -9
PAAXXYX PAAXXYX 0 0 2 1
PAAXYXX PAAXYXX 0 0 2 1
PAAYXXX PAAYXXX 0 0 1 1
PAAYYXX PAAYYXX 0 0 1 -9
PAAYYYX PAAYYYX 0 0 2 2
PAAAAAB PAAAAAB 0 0 1 2
```

Note that if some IDs in FILE1 are found neither in FILE2 or FILE3, I would like to retain the original value. Furthermore it is crucial that the order of the output is not changed. It would be fine to solve the problem in two steps, first comparing FILE1 to FILE2 and then FILE1 to FILE3.

I feel that my problem might potentially be solved by running sed in a for-loop but so far I have been unsuccessful. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In awk, using ARGIND

```
awk 'ARGIND~"1|2"{a[$1]=ARGIND;next}a[$1]{$NF=a[$1]}1' FILE2 FILE3 FILE1

PAAXXXX PAAXXXX 0 0 1 -9
PAAXXXY PAAXXXY 0 0 1 -9
PAAXXYX PAAXXYX 0 0 2 1
PAAXYXX PAAXYXX 0 0 2 1
PAAYXXX PAAYXXX 0 0 1 1
PAAYYXX PAAYYXX 0 0 1 -9
PAAYYYX PAAYYYX 0 0 2 2
PAAAAAB PAAAAAB 0 0 1 2
```

Comment: Fantastic solution! Precisely what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note: This answer is very specific for Gnu Awk (gawk).  See `ARGIND` in https://docs.freebsd.org/info/gawk/gawk.info.Auto-set.html

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Yep probably should've mentioned that.

Comment: @User112638726 Try to inline an explanation of what happens under the hood.

Comment: `ARGIND~"1|2"` will function in this case but that syntax in general is a little odd and fragile compared to `ARGIND~/1|2/` or better `ARGIND~/[12]/` or better `ARGIND~/^[12]$/`or best `ARGIND<3`.

Comment: @EdMorton How is it more fragile than `ARGIND~/1|2/` or `ARGIND~/[12]/` ? I Understand i could have put anchors on but in this case it didn't really matter. Also I thought of `ARGIND<3` after i had already written the answer, and as it worked i just decided to leave it.

Comment: "odd and fragile" - it's more on the odd than fragile side compared to those 2 since you're telling awk with `~` to do a regexp comparison comparison but then giving it a string to compare to (`"1|2"`) which awk then has to internally convert to a regexp (`/1|2/`) instead of just writing the regexp. It's like wanting to increment a var by 2 and giving awk a string`var += "2"` instead of an integer `var += 2`. Sure it'll function as intended since awk is smart enough to convert it for you but it just makes no sense to write it that way.

Comment: @EdMorton I'll agree it's odd, i just wrote it quick and didn't really think. Shouldn't really make a difference here though.

Comment: Except that had I not commented the OP might have gone away thinking that is the best, awkish way to write that condition and in other applications/contexts he'd be in for a surprise.

Comment: @EdMorton I can't think of a situation where this would actively cause harm doing it this way, I'm not even sure it would in a CPU heavy script. But okay, edit the answer if you think it will, or downvote it or whatever.

Comment: I'm not going to edit or downvote it as it will function fine in this context, I just thought the OP should know that there's better ways to do it. If you post a question about issues related to using unanchored strings in a regexp context I'll be happy to answer with examples but it's not something I want to try to show in unformatted comments. The issues are not about efficiency.